# How to start Firefox using a fresh session?

Tags: firefox

Sometimes Firefox crashes and when I go to start it again by double clicking on the icon, it tries to reopen all sites I had open in the tabs, and this can cause the same problem again.

Is there a way to tell Firefox when it starts, to always start a fresh session and not try to reopen everything that was open when I closed it?

I am using version 12 on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the toolbar, go to *Edit* -> *Preferences*. In the General tab, the first entry "Startup" is for what happens when you open Firefox. Make sure that it's NOT "Show my windows and tabs from last time". If that option isn't selected and Firefox crashes or was forced quit. It will ask you if you want to restore your previous session when you reopen it.